# How to check if the output value is 4 or not?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

Following code isn't working. Please help.

```
        WebElement output=driver.findElement(By.id("XLEW_1_3_1"));

        System.out.print (output.getText());    
        if (output.getText()=="4")
        {

            System.out.print("Correct output");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Incorrect output");

        }
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: sorry but i do not have access to the html. I have tried if (output.equals("4")) but this is also not working. Please assist.

Comment: Goto the site in a browser, right click and select view source from the menu to get the HTML code.

Comment: Thanks. Here you go.view-source:https://ssccust1.spreadsheethosting.com/1/59/226a21cef25ec5/for_automation/for_automation.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, its working fine for the sample given

```
driver.get("https://ssccust1.spreadsheethosting.com/1/59/226a21cef25ec5/for_automation/for_automation.htm");
        driver.findElement(By.id("XLEW_1_1_1")).sendKeys("4"+Keys.TAB);
        String output=driver.findElement(By.id("XLEW_1_3_1")).getAttribute("value");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        if (output.equals("4"))
        {

            System.out.print("Correct output");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Incorrect output");

        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But why do we need to do "sendKeys("4"+Keys.TAB)"? There are two input fields. I have entered 2 in both fields. So, the output will be 4 because i have applied sum formula. All I need to test if the output is 4 or not?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. There was a problem with Threadsleep. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: @shama for testing I have Given tab,you can remove the "Tab" key